# How to change the xml class name using fasterxml jackson?

Tags: java, json, xml, jackson, fasterxml

I am trying to figure out how to change the root node name using jackson fasterxml.

For example:

```
public class Car {
    @JsonProperty("engine-type") 
    String engineType = "v8";
}

public class Ford extends Car {
}

Ford car = new Ford();
ObjectMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
System.out.println(xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(this));
```

results in:

```
<Ford><engine-type>v8</engine-type></Ford>
```

This is what I want:

1. The root node to be named car.
2. I want Car to be lowercase in the xml:

For example:

```
<car><engine-type>v8</engine-type></car>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 12):

I think you could find your solution here: [How to deserialize XML with annotations using FasterXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23632419/how-to-deserialize-xml-with-annotations-using-fasterxml?rq=1)
Why don't you use @JacksonXmlRootElement like:

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "car")
public class Ford extends Car {
}
```