# Spring boot XML change root element name

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-boot, jackson-dataformat-xml

I wrote a spring boot application to accept a Http get Request and send a XML response as the output.I need to get following XML as output over HTTP

```
<response xmlns="">
    <userId>235</userId>
    <amount>345.0</amount>
</response>
```

And my DTO class is follows,

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "response")
public class CgPayment {
    @XmlElement
    private String userId;
    @XmlElement
    private double amount;

    @XmlElement
    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setAmount(double amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public double getAmount() {

        return amount;
    }
}
```

But i'm getting following response as the Output.

```
<CgPayment xmlns="">
    <userId>235</userId>
    <amount>345.0</amount>
</CgPayment>
```

How can I change the root element.The response type is APPLICATION_XML_VALUE

Comment: Try `@JacksonXmlRootElement` [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23632419/how-to-deserialize-xml-with-annotations-using-fasterxml?rq=1). Or `XmlElement` annotation with the `name` attribute set to `Response` could do the trick. See this : http://www.duanqu.tech/questions/359704/jackson-annotation-how-to-rename-element-names

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "response")` at the level of the class.

Javadoc : http://static.javadoc.io/com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat/jackson-dataformat-xml/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/xml/annotation/JacksonXmlRootElement.html

Answer (score 11):

You are using JAXB specific annotations, but Jackson to marshall your response. To make JAXB annotations work with Jackson, you have to include the `jackson-module-jaxb-annotations` inside your `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-module-jaxb-annotations</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Additionally, you have to register the `JaxbAnnotationModule` for your configuration. I think the easiest way to achieve that with Spring Boot is to register a Bean of type `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer` like this:

```
@Component
public class JacksonCustomizer implements Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer {
    @Override
    public void customize(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jacksonObjectMapperBuilder) {
        jacksonObjectMapperBuilder.modulesToInstall(new JaxbAnnotationModule());
}
```

or

```
@Bean
Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer jacksonCustomizer() {
    return (mapperBuilder) -> mapperBuilder.modulesToInstall(new JaxbAnnotationModule());
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. spring uses jackson by default, so installing the `JaxbAnnotationModule` to use JAXB annotations is required. As of `2.9.0` the extra dependency is also no longer necessary.

Comment: This works for me, I have added Bean dependency in the SpringBootApplication

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change class name to Response ?? I think that your marshaller is getting name from name of class.

i found this (maybe it will be helpful)

> If type() is JAXBElement.class , then namespace() and name() point to a 
>    factory method with XmlElementDecl. The XML element name is the
>   element name from the factory method's XmlElementDecl annotation or if
>   an element from its substitution group (of which it is a head element)
>   has been substituted in the XML document, then the element name is
>   from the XmlElementDecl on the substituted element.If type() is not
>   JAXBElement.class, then the XML element name is the XML element name
>   statically associated with the type using the annotation
>   XmlRootElement on the type. If the type is not annotated with an
>   XmlElementDecl, then it is an error. If type() is not
>   JAXBElement.class, then this value must be "".

Comment: What i need is the response as the root node name(Starting letter is simple). I have changed my question. Thanks.